# Custom AJAX update outside order review table in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, woocommerce, checkout

On my WooCommerce checkout page, I am showing a notification before the order review section based on the cart total. I have included the following code in my `functions.php` file of my child theme:

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
    // Get cart total
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    
    // Compare
    if ( $cart_total == 0.01 ) {
        echo '<p>' . __( 'My message', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```

The problem with this code is that the notice does not appear if a coupon is applied to the order, such that the cart total equals 0.01 euro, but instead only appears after the page is refreshed.

How can I alter this code such that the notice is added/removed through AJAX?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The following code solved my issue

```
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
  $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
  if ( $cart_total == 0.01 ) {
    echo '<p class="notice">' . __( 'My message', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>';
  }
  ?>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('.woocommerce-remove-coupon').click(function(){
    jQuery('.notice').hide();
  });
  </script>
  
  <?php
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_cart_contents', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to add a custom message based on the cart total you can simply work with **Javascript** (or **JQuery**).

Using the hook `woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review` the message will be shown only if, when the page is loaded, the total of the cart is equal to `0.01`.

Here you can find the list of WooCommerce Javascript events:

- [Woocommerce documentation | list of JS events](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/342148/woocommerce-documentation-list-of-js-events)

You could then add something like this into your active theme's **functions.php** file *(it's just an idea)*:

```
// show or hide a custom message in checkout based on cart total
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'show_hide_message_based_on_cart_total' );
function show_hide_message_based_on_cart_total() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // the script is triggered every time the checkout updates
        jQuery(document.body).on('updated_checkout', function(){
            // gets the values of the cart total and the discount total by removing the currency symbol and converting the string to a number
            var cartTotal = jQuery('table.shop_table tr.cart-subtotal bdi').text().replace("€","").replace(",",".").trim();
            var coupon = jQuery('table.shop_table tr.cart-discount span.amount').text().replace("€","").replace(",",".").trim();
            if ( cartTotal - coupon == 0.01 ) {
                // show the message
                jQuery('<span id="custom_message">Custom Message</span>').insertBefore('#order_review');
            } else {
                // removes the message
                jQuery('#custom_message').remove();
            } 
        });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: This is a nice attempt!

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you. Although the ideal solution should be the Ajax call you used.

Comment: But I learned from your linked thread about `applied_coupon_in_checkout` and  `removed_coupon_in_checkout ` JS Event that exist since WC 4+, So thanks for that! +1

Answer (score 1):

The following will show or hide your custom message based on checkout coupon events via Ajax and on cart contents total amount:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review', 10, 0 );
function action_woocommerce_checkout_before_order_review () {
    // Here below set your message
    $message    = __( 'My message', 'woocommerce' );
    $threshold  = 0.01; // Here your targeted subtotal amount

    $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    echo '<p class="custom-message" style="'. ( $cart_total > $threshold ? '' : 'display:none;' ) .'">' . $message . '</p>';

    // jQuery Ajax
    wc_enqueue_js( "jQuery( function($){
        if (typeof wc_checkout_params === 'undefined') return false;

        function checkoutCouponEvent() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: wc_checkout_params.ajax_url,
                data: {
                    'action': 'checkout_coupon',
                    'ccevent': 'Yes'
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    if ( parseFloat(response) == " . $threshold . " ) {
                        $('.custom-message').show();
                    } else {
                        $('.custom-message').hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        $(document.body).on('applied_coupon_in_checkout removed_coupon_in_checkout', function( event ){
            setTimeout(function(){
                checkoutCouponEvent();
            }, event.type === 'removed_coupon_in_checkout' ? 350 : 0 );
        });
    });" );
}

// Ajax receiver function
add_action( 'wp_ajax_checkout_coupon', 'checkout_coupon_ajax_receiver' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checkout_coupon', 'checkout_coupon_ajax_receiver' );
function checkout_coupon_ajax_receiver() {
    if ( isset($_POST['ccevent']) && $_POST['ccevent'] ) {
        echo WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();
    }
    wp_die();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.